# firefox navigation,delete keys not working

Tags: firefox

i have written this code

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but navigation,delete keys not working in Firefox(43.0.4)

Answer (score 0):

Based on some research [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), it seems that the character codes for the keys may be incorrect. Accorinng to the article the following is mapping based on backspace and directional keys:

- backspace: 8
- left arrow:37
- right arrow: 39
- down arrow: 40
- up arrow: 38

hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, after rewritting the code as function isNumberDashboardReporting(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && !(charCode == 8 || charCode == 37 || charCode == 39 || charCode == 40 || charCode == 38 )) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
 the also up,down keys are not workng

Comment: how is the function being called? e.g. are you calling `onkeypress` within an input?

Comment: onpaste='return isNumberDashboardReporting(event)' onkeypress='return isNumberDashboardReporting(event)' in html

Comment: Can you paste the whole html tag. Is it an input field?